# Is there any difference in installing Apache SuperSet on Ubuntu or on python virtual environment?

Tags: business-intelligence, apache-superset

I installed Apache Super-Set in Python virtual environment. I was wondering does it make any difference if I use Super-Set in Ubuntu or on Python Virtual Environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your question, unless you are confusing Apache Superset with another tool going by Superset also.

Apache Superset is built on python, so in order to install it in Ubuntu you have two options:

- Install python and in it install Apache Superset
- Use Docker or another virtualization software similar to it to download a container with Python and Apache Superset

Comment: My question is, consider this you have two machines one is running on Ubuntu you install superset on it and there is a second machine which has python virtual environment in it and you install super set within that python virtual environment. If I use superset on Ubuntu and make something. Will I be able to do the same thing in Super-Set on the machine which uses Python Virtual Environment for using Superset? or will there be any difference?

Comment: In short, yes, it's the same. I'm not python expert, but a virtual environment is kind of a "encapsulated" environment so you don't interfere with other projects using python also, but different libraries that might conflict, so you install in each virtual environment the libraries you need for your project, and those libraries aren't available for the others virtual environments.